# Consider version context of old questions related to evolving games?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, game-versions

Some games enjoy a lively audience and a dedicated development team and so evolve over a period of years. Arqade has been around long enough to have questions that were asked at a time when a particular capability either didn't exist in a game and now does or was accomplished in a different way today than it had been in the past.

Generally, I believe an answer should keep the context of the question in mind. If a question was asked five years ago, and someone chooses to answer that question today, the answer's author should consider that the context of the question is for a version of the game that existed then.

A good example is Minecraft. Many of the admin capabilities that are available today weren't available five years ago. I believe that answering a question that was asked five years ago by saying, "Today, you can do it like this", isn't useful in the context of the question if the game evolved significantly in that time.

Am I wrong about this? Should I be looking at this in a different way?

Comment: If you found a question about a problem you were having but all of the answers were out of date would you be happy or unhappy about that?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That sounds like a bit of a red herring.  Outdated answers can still help readers draw conclusions on what the new method might be, giving them at least something to work with.  It's also a very good reason to post an updated answer, which can also help future readers.  Neither case lends itself well to reasking a question because of an arbitrary time limit.

Comment: @Frank It was just a succinct comment/pointer to help the OP here reach their own conclusions. Sometimes it helps to think in a different frame of mind from an actual scenario you have probably encountered in the past.

Answer (score 3):

We're not just looking at answering the problem the user had at the time of his question, but we also want to help people with the same problem today with a more recent version. Again, we don't want to help a single person, we want to help as many people as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is wanted to help as many people as possible. I personally think if you are going to do something of that sort, you better put a heading that says (mainly for Minecraft) 1.X+. I think it should be okay as long as it is made clear that it is indeed the future.